# Можно ли работать с сайтом если нету домена

Tags: сервер

У меня такая проблемка: я заказ хостинг на wmz, но домен я не купил, можно ли как то работать с сайтом ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хостинг должен был дать IP адрес, по которому доступен ваш сайт. Прочитайте внимательно письма которые приходили от хостера.

Answer (score 1):

У  большинства хостеров есть возможность работать  с сайтом по  url типа

сайт.сервер.хостер.домен